# Erros ao Reinstalar o Microsoft Visual Stúdio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin

Fui desinstalar pelo Iobit o Microsoft Visual Studio & Xamarin, dai tentei reinstalar e está dando esses erros.

Eu já tentei desinstalar excluindo as pastas dos arquivos e os Registros no Windows, limpei os registros entre outros e mesmo assim não consigo reinstalar sempre da esses erros.

Alguém pode me ajudar por gentileza?

[image: Erros]

Comment: Acho que hoje esta tendo algum problema com a microsoft, aqui na empresa estamos com 2 maquinas assim, após a tentativa de update.

Comment: Só quero aprender Xamarin, mais está dificil, a microsoft tirou o Xamarin Studio e enfiou junto no Visual Studio.

Comment: pege o file log é poste junto com a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O instalador do Visual Studio remove apenas o "core" do VS,use essa ferramenta Para limpar os programas restantes 
https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller
e mesmo assim verifique se ficou algum ainda instalado,após a remoção de todos os aplicativos é recomendado reiniciar o computador,após reiniciar pode proceder com a instalação do VS2015

Caso a Ferramenta acima não funcione
essa com certeza ira te ajudar com o problema(Eu mesmo utilizei ela pra atualizar pro VS2017 deletando tudo antes)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5qge4B7EJUENlAyNXAzdVQ0MEE/view?usp=sharing